# Windows 8 hangs with "Preparing Automatic Repair" when booting from grub

Tags: windows-8, boot, grub

**The past:**

- Had Grub Legacy installed booting linux sucessfully.
- Made a backup of Grub's mbr with `dd if=/dev/sda of=backupmbr bs=512 count=1`
- Installed Windows 8 Pro.
- Windows 8 overwrote MBR, as expected.
- Recovered with dd for windows: ``dd if=backupmbr of=\Harddisk.... bs=512 count=1`

**The present:**

- Grub is loading.
- Linux is loading sucessfully.
- When booting Windows 8 it hangs on a *Preparing Automatic Repair* screen. There's no disk activity, it just hangs forever. Tried to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to show Windows's boot options, with no luck (actually, I don't how to do it, I tried to keep both keys pressed before selecting `Windows 8` entry and tried to smash them repeatdly, and they both failed (the last one resulted on keyboard beeping))

**The future:**

- Windows 8 booting sucessfully again, by selecting the corresponding entry on Grub Legacy.

I need some help with the *future* part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's a workaround (I'm the OP):

- Boot from Windows 8 CD, open command prompt and type: `BootRec.exe /fixmbr`
- Restart, log into Windows 8, open Admin command prompt and type:

  ```
   bcdedit /create /d “Grub” /application bootsector
  ```

  It returns an ID between braces `{..}`

  ```
   bcdedit /set {..} device partition=d: 
   bcdedit /set {..}  path \backupmbr    [My mbr backup is on D:\backupmbr] 
   bcdedit /displayorder {..} /addlast
  ```

  Then, when restarting, after more than 40s Windows would show a metro-style menu prompting me to choose between Windows 8 and Grub. Choosing Windows 8 goes instantly to Windows 8 Start Screen (so Windows boots completely and **then** ask you what to do!)  while choosing Grub goes to Grub after another age (cause Windows needs to reboot). This was unacceptable. Running the following line:

  ```
   bcdedit /default {..}
  ```

  Solves the problem, ie, shows a non metro selection menu between Windows and Grub **before** loading the whole Windows.

  Finally, if I select Grub and, then, inside Grub, select too boot Windows then it still hangs on the "Preparing Automatic Repair" screen. So I can boot all my OS's but it was not as I wanted. I still can't *make Grub Legacy boot Windows 8 without being stucked on "Preparing Automatic Repair"*